# So tell me now - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

So tell me know, can you figure out,
The clues I'll give are all about
A subject many really quite hate,
The moment they hear it, from the gate.
It really is useful, as science would say,
Scientific conclusions use it every day.
The chances too are great, can you see
If you use it, or hear what they may be.
Consider now these clues, not so mean.
Stay away from numbered errors, as they're seen.
So check the clues, the hidden and viewed
Something's lurking, what do you conclude?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Statistics?

So tell me know, can you figure out,
The clues I'll give are all about
A subject many really quite hate,
The moment they hear it, from the gate.

> Many people have a negative attitude towards statistics: there are lies, there are damned lies, and there is statistics.

It really is useful, as science would say,
Scientific conclusions use it every day.

> Statistics is used everywhere in science, from physics over chemistry and biology to economics.

The chances too are great, can you see
If you use it, or hear what they may be.
Consider now these clues, not so mean.
Stay away from numbered errors, as they're seen.

> "chances", "mean", "errors": standard terms in statistics

So check the clues, the hidden and viewed
Something's lurking, what do you conclude?

Comment: Ah! You beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: Well done, and the first! That was fast.

Comment: ... but you failed to catch the most obvious clue :-/

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it is

> Statistics / Probability

And the hidden clue is the first letter of each line:

> STATISTICSSS

So tell me know, can you figure out,
The clues I'll give are all about
A subject many really quite hate,

> *I* certainly did not enjoy my statistics courses

The moment they hear it, from the gate.

> "From the gate" could refer to various kinds of animal racing and odds are given in all such races for the purposes of betting

It really is useful, as science would say,
Scientific conclusions use it every day.

> All good scientific conclusions based on data will include a statistical probability of the conclusions being accurate

The chances too are great, can you see
If you use it, or hear what they may be.

> "Chances" is another term for probability

Consider now these clues, not so mean.

> "Mean" is a term used in statistics to mean the average

Stay away from numbered errors, as they're seen.

> We want to avoid errors in data collection as that'll mess up the conclusion. Small errors are one indicator of good data.

So check the clues, the hidden and viewed
Something's lurking, what do you conclude?

Comment: Just beat out by Martin. Lawrence found the hidden clue, but didn't say what it was.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> Statistics.

Martin was too quick with the rest of the clues, but here's the hidden clue:

> Acrostic

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like

> Math

A subject many really quite hate,
The moment they hear it, from the gate.

> Many people dislike math

It really is useful, as science would say,
Scientific conclusions use it every day.

> Math is useful in science!

The chances too are great, can you see
If you use it, or hear what they may be.

> Probability is part of math

Consider now these clues, not so mean.
Stay away from numbered errors, as they're seen.

> "numbered" -> "numbers" -> "math"

Comment: Very close, and on the right track, but not quite. There are a couple more clues you are not finding.

Comment: The extra clue is *probably* related to the *gates* of *horse racing*... ;)